# Batch file that connects to server based on vlan

Tags: batch-file, cmd, automation, winpe, vlan

This is a snippet of my automation script for imaging from a particular server based on vlan. The script checks its IP and what vlan it is in then using that it connects to a particular server. My problem is that I am getting an "if is unexpected at this time" error. Please help.

```
:getvlan
for /f "tokens=2 delims=:" %%a in ('ipconfig ^| find "IPv4 Address"') do set IP=%%a
for /f "tokens=3 delims=." %%j in ('echo %IP%') do set vlan=%%j

if %vlan% GEQ 100 (if %vlan% LEQ 119 (
   set servernowack=server1
   set seshtype=M
) if %vlan% GEQ 130 (if %vlan% LEQ 139 (
   set servernowack=server2
   set seshtype=D
) if %vlan% GEQ 140 (if %vlan% LEQ 149 (
   set servernowack=server3
   set seshtype=D
) if %vlan% GEQ 150 (if %vlan% LEQ 159 (
   set servernowack=server4
   set seshtype=M
) if %vlan% GEQ 160 (if %vlan% LEQ 169 (
   set servernowack=server5
   set seshtype=D
) else (
   goto fail
)
goto getserverip
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a lot more opening than closing parentheses. Therefore `cmd.exe` fails to determine the block for each `if` in your batch code, a simple syntax mistake easy to solve.

```
@echo off
:getvlan
for /f "tokens=2 delims=:" %%a in ('%windir%\system32\ipconfig.exe ^| %windir%\system32\find.exe "IPv4 Address"') do set IP=%%a
for /f "tokens=3 delims=." %%j in ('echo %IP%') do set vlan=%%j

if %vlan% GEQ 100 (
   if %vlan% LEQ 119 (
      set servernowack=server1
      set seshtype=M
      goto getserverip
   )
)
if %vlan% GEQ 130 (
   if %vlan% LEQ 139 (
      set servernowack=server2
      set seshtype=D
      goto getserverip
   )
)
if %vlan% GEQ 140 (
   if %vlan% LEQ 149 (
      set servernowack=server3
      set seshtype=D
      goto getserverip
   )
)
if %vlan% GEQ 150 (
   if %vlan% LEQ 159 (
      set servernowack=server4
      set seshtype=M
      goto getserverip
   )
)
if %vlan% GEQ 160 (
   if %vlan% LEQ 169 (
      set servernowack=server5
      set seshtype=D
      goto getserverip
   )
)
echo Error: Failed to determine vlan!
goto :EOF

:getserverip
```